# My wallet got hacked - I do not know what do to

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, etherscan, myetherwallet, raw-transaction

Someone hacked my eth wallet and when ever I deposit ethereum to the wallet my deposited ethereum is sent directly to his wallet automatically.. Pls how can I stop this issue because my wallet has my useful coins which I want to withdraw. I need help guys please. Am not a programmer
But please guys help me am running mad

[image]

Comment: which wallet you are using?. Are you using your own ethereum node?

Comment: Brother am using trust app erc20 ethereum wallet. But I lost my private key in 2018 and I have found it in this new year and after successful recovery the wallet I found that some of my tokens where taken and the few which are remaining are like trup because when I deposit gas fee to withdraw them the deposited gas fees are taken as soon as it arrives in the wallet.